# Visual studio code: An error occurred setting up the container

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

When i run visual studio code and trying to connect following the tutorial from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers and run a python example.   I get the terminal output below.  I can run nodejs container from the demo fine, it seams to be just python.  Any ideas how i correct this issue?

```
[38817 ms] Start: Run: docker volume create --label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python --label vsch.local.repository.unique=false vsc-remote-sample
[39903 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python --filter label=vsch.local.repository.volume=vsc-remote-sample --filter label=vsch.local.repository.folder=vscode-remote-try-python --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[45503 ms] Start: Run: docker build -f c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.112.0\scripts\volumeBootstrap.Dockerfile -t vsc-volume-bootstrap c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.112.0\scripts
[47800 ms] Error: Unable to start terminal process: CreateProcess failed
        at new WindowsPtyAgent (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\node-pty\lib\windowsPtyAgent.js:77:36)
        at new WindowsTerminal (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\node-pty\lib\windowsTerminal.js:49:24)
        at Object.spawn (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\node-pty\lib\index.js:28:12)
        at c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.112.0\dist\extension.js:1:5201
        at async Object.t.runCommand (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.112.0\dist\extension.js:1:8440)
        at async c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.112.0\dist\extension.js:1:111138
        at async Object.k [as cloneAndBuildRepository] (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.112.0\dist\extension.js:1:110997)
        at async Object.t.openDockerfileRepoDevContainer (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.112.0\dist\extension.js:1:157194)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75885#issuecomment-504375855), or [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57285#issuecomment-417046922) help you?

Comment: it was the second link.  It was permision that caused the issue.  I ran as admin and its now working, I'll get my IT support on the case to correct this for my standard user accoount.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this occur on Ubuntu 22 when a Docker image was created specifically for CUDA, and I needed to install the "NVidia Container Toolkit".